# Redux-form and the handleSubmit, onSubmit chaos

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to wrap my head around redux-form and it's onSubmit, handleSubmit.

> I have a component (see below) which has it's own local state and should handle it's own submit.

```
// NoteForm.js
class NoteForm extends Component {

    state = {
        tags: []
    };

    handleAddItem = (e, {value}) => {
        this.setState({
            tags: [{text: value, value}, ...this.state.tags],
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>

                <Field

                    name='description'
                    component={TextAreaField}
                    maxLength='5'
                    label='Description'/>

                <Field
                    name='tags'
                    onAddItem={this.handleAddItem}
                    component={DropdownField}
                    label='Tags'/>

                <Form.Field control={Button} primary className='submit-btn' type='submit'>
                    Login
                </Form.Field>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
    handleSubmit: note => console.log(note)//dispatch(addNote(note))
});

export default reduxForm({form: 'noteForm', validate})(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NoteForm));
```

### But for some reason I keep receiving the Proxy Event instead of the values.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your HOCs since redux form is not receiving props from connected component. The order of HOC is important because connect supplies the underlying component with prop and that prop should be received by `reduxForm` which it can then modify and pass to its underlying component

You you need to note that `reduxForm` HOC expects the prop to be `onSubmit` which it takes and supplies the prop `handleSubmit` to the underlying component with some modifications(like supplying the data values) and hence you would write

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
   onSubmit: note => console.log(note)//dispatch(addNote(note))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(
     reduxForm({form: 'noteForm', validate}
)(NoteForm));
```

Comment: This is still receiving the Proxy object, but thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I updated my answer with a couple of additions and some more explanation. Hope it helps